# One to many relationship in laravel extracting the latest timestamp

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have a one to many relationships in the database, and I am trying to extract the latest. The table names are `notification` and `alertFrequency`, they have models for each. I want to write a query that will get me the latest time stamp associated to a specific website in the notifications table. The `alertFequency` table has only 2 columns namely `notification_id` and `created_at`. the following are my model notification modl

```
   class Notification extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['id','website_url','email','slack_channel','check_frequency','alert_frequency','speed_frequency','active'];

    public function statuses(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Status')->withPivot('values')->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function alertFrequencies(){     
        return $this->hasMany('App\AlertFrequency');
    }
    // trail versions
    public function alert(){
        $items = AlertFrequency::select('alertFrequencies.created_at')//Any column you want to fetch
        ->join('notifications', 'notifications.id', '=', 'alertFrequencies.notification_id')
        ->orderBy('alertFrequencies.created_at','desc')
        ->first();
        if($items == null){
            return null;
        }
        return $items->created_at->toDateTimeString();

class AlertFrequency extends Model{
    protected $table = 'alertFrequencies';
    public function notification(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Notification');
    }  
}
```

inside the `notification` model i wrote a function that is expected to extract the data(i.e the latest time stamp of a specific website in the `notification` table) more over the notification_id is a foreign key in the `alertFrequency` table. the alert function is as follows

```
public function alert(){
    $alert_timestamp = AlertFrequency::with('notification')->select('created_at')->orderBy('created_at','desc')->first();
    //$alert_timestamp=$alert_timestamp->created_at->toDateTimeString();
    if($alert_timestamp==null){
        return false;
    }       
   return $alert_timestamp;
}
```

it is returnning created_at time stamp but not the latset related to a specific website. i would apperciate your help?

in the database i have two websites added one at 12:18 and the second ata 12:24..... sorry i dont know how i can post the database here.

Comment: You are only 'selecting' `created_at`. So it only returns it. Can you try to add the fields you want in the select() or better explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: what I am trying to achieve is that, when a new website is added in the notification table, notification_id of the new website will be added in the alertFrequency table with a created_at time stamp, there could be many website added in the notification table and their notification_id is a foreign key in the alerFrequency table, then i want to extract the latest created_at of a specific website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly You can not apply `orderBy()` on relation you need to use `join()`

Just try this. Hope it helps

```
$alert_timestamp = AlertFrequency::select('alertFrequencies.created_at')//Any column you want to fetch
    ->join('notification', 'notification.notification_id', '=', 'alertFrequencies.notification_id')
    ->orderBy('alertFrequencies.created_at','desc')
    ->get();
```

Comment: tnx i get new insights. i will try your way!

Comment: i already voted for your answer. i have a question. i added to websites in to the notification table. in the database, the two websites have different time stamp, when i have var_dumo it, it only give me the last time stamp 2 times. what i expected to get was, the time stamp for both websites, not only ine time stamp 2 times.?

Comment: @abrahamfoto you have accepted the answer not upvoted so upvote it to find others easily. can you post your var_dump() and database record so that i can understand more about your problems

Comment: moreover i changed the get into first... Because it complained about the collection:error :::  Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$created_at

Comment: not yet. even when i read your code carefully, it returns the latest time stamp in general, not specific to a website.i want to get the latest time stamp for a specific website not the general latest time stamp.

Comment: so there you can specify the `where()` after join like `->where('notification.website', $yourwebsite)`

Comment: i can do that , but it wil be hard coded. i have many websites, it should be done automatically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133448/discussion-between-jaymin-panchal-and-abraham-foto).